# Complicated R Function for picking max Values

Tags: r, function

I have a data frame...

```
a <- c(6,9,12,13,15,20)
b <- c(1,12,36,2,48,3)
c <- c(50,0,2,35,12,60)
df = data.frame(a,b,c)
#   a  b  c
#1  6  1 50
#2  9 12  0
#3 12 36  2
#4 13  2 35
#5 15 48 12
#6 20  3 60
```

What I would like to do is

- Start with the first number in the first column
- Then pick the number in the next column that is higher in value
- Then pick the number in the next column (third) that is higher in value than the value from the second column...etc (for up to 100 columns)
- Since there could be multiple instances where a number is higher (example: 6, 12, 50 is one combination. 6, 36, 50 is another, etc.  The function has to take into account all of the combinations.
- Then go the the second number in the first column and start over, etc

if there is no higher number, the function simply terminates and only reports the last number that was higher

The output is a data frame where each column is the combination

Is this possible to do in R as a function?

The output can be can be a data frame of the following format

```
c1 <- c(6,12,50)
c2 <- c(6,36,50)
c3 <- c(6,48,50)
c4 <- c(9,12,50)
c5 <- c(9,36,50)
c6 <- c(9,48,50)
c7 <- c(12,36,50)
c8 <- c(12,48,50)
c9 <- c(13,36,50)
c10 <- c(13,48,50)
c11 <- c(15,36,50)
c12 <- c(15,48,50)
c13 <- c(20,36,50)
c14 <- c(20,48,50)
etc
df1 <- data.frame(c1, c2, c3, c4, etc)
#  c1 c2 c3 c4 ...
#1  6  6  6  9 ...
#2 12 36 48 12 ...
#3 50 50 50 50 ...
```

Comment: Could you show the expected output for the example dataset? It will make it easier to understand.

Comment: What happens if you pick a number in one column, and there is no higher number in the next column? Or is that not possible?

Comment: @akrun - edits have been made to address your questions

Comment: @JohnPaul edits have been madee to address your question

Comment: I'm having problems parsing your explanations. Can you please follow akrun's request and add the expected output of your example to the question?

Comment: @Roland Done.  hopefully it helps to clarify

Answer (score 2):

This gives you all the combinations where the numbers are increasing from `first` column to `last` column

```
 df1 <- do.call(`expand.grid`,lapply(df, unique))
 df2 <- df1[Reduce(`&`,lapply(1:(ncol(df1)-1),
                function(i) df1[,i+1]>df1[,i])),]

 head(df2)
 #    a  b  c
 #7   6 12 50
 #8   9 12 50
 #13  6 36 50
 #14  9 36 50
 #15 12 36 50
 #16 13 36 50

 dim(df2)
 #[1] 30  3
```

Comment: this looks promising...let me test it out